# Detect Eddystone-TLM with android beacon library

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

I configure [android beacon library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) to detect Eddystone packets

```
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(context);
    // Detect the main identifier (UID) frame:
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
    setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));
// Detect the telemetry (TLM) frame:
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
    setBeaconLayout("x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"));
// Detect the URL frame:
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
    setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-21v"));
beaconManager.bind(this);
```

Beacon in never detected in Android beacon library.

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {      


beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);       

beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons,
            Region region) {


        if (beacons.size() > 0) {
            Extra.log("Beacons detected", "info");
            //Process beacons data...

        }
    }
});

  try {

      beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region(
              "myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
  }
}
```

Test:

- If beacon is configured in Eddystone-TML I can detect beacon telemetry data with manufacturer app.
- If beacon is configured in Eddystone-TML I can´t detect beacon with library.
- If beacon is configured in Eddystone-UID I can detect correctly beacon with  library and manufacturer app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to check to make sure you are not detecting at all:

- Make sure `onBeaconServiceConnect()` gets called.  Add a `Log.d` statement to be sure.
- Make sure your app has obtained location permissions if you are testing on Android 6+.  See [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html) for more info.

**EDIT:** For Eddystone-TLM, the library does not provide a separate beacon instance in the ranging callback.  The library intead treats this frame type as *supplemental* to a primary beacon frame like AltBeacon or Eddystone-UID.  So it will only provide the info from Eddystone-TLM if another primary beacon frame is also detected coming from the same device.

The way it works is that when a beacon frame like AltBeacon or Eddystone-UID is detected, a `Beacon` object is created and passed to the ranging callback.  When an Eddystone-TLM frame is detected coming from the same MAC address as the a primary beacon frame, the telemetry information is attached to the object of the primary beacon frame.  To access this info you call:

```
// Do we have telemetry data?
if (beacon.getExtraDataFields().size() > 0) {
    long telemetryVersion = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(0);
    long batteryMilliVolts = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(1);
    long pduCount = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(3);
    long uptime = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(4);

    Log.d(TAG, "The above beacon is sending telemetry version "+telemetryVersion+
                ", has been up for : "+uptime+" seconds"+
                ", has a battery level of "+batteryMilliVolts+" mV"+
                ", and has transmitted "+pduCount+" advertisements.");

}
```

Comment: onBeaconServiceConnect() is called once in start. didRangeBeaconsInRegion with beacons.size()==0 is called a lot of times even if beacon is off. Device is Android 5.1.

Comment: I test library in same device with Eddystone - UID and Albeacon beacons and works ok. Problem is only in Eddystone - TLM beacon.

Comment: Problem solved enabling in beacon config = UID + TLM. It was only TLM and that was the problem.

Comment: @davidgyoung is there any limitation which allows to attach telemetry only to AltBeacon or Eddystone-UID frames? In the application I'm working on we are using iBeacon and the beacon itself advertises as iBeacon, sBeacon and all three Eddystones, so it could be great to have TLM as a supplement to iBeacon (or any other primary frame type) too.

Comment: The library will attach telemetry to other beacon frames based on the MAC address of the beacon.  So if the beacon is advertising iBeacon and Eddystone-TLM, I believe the attachment will work (although I have not tested this config.)